# PHP MongoDB Regex is accepting parts of words

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
$nameRegEx = new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($userName, 'i');
$userDB = $userCollection->findOne(['userName' => $nameRegEx]);
```

In my imagination this regex (option i) only says case insensitive as mentioned [into docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

Given `$userName = "go"` the curser `$userDB` would find a document with `userName` being "g" as well.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong ? Do I understand this option in a wrong way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your regex does not specify when the string starts or end (`^` and `$` respectively).

Try this out:

```
$nameRegEx = new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^'.preg_quote($userName).'$', 'i');
```

Also: `i` passed as the second parameter, means that your search will be case-insensitive. Maybe this will lead to wrong results as well.

Comment: Remember to escape `$userName` for use as a part of the regex literal or else the end-user can enter a malformed regex and break the search.

Comment: `preg_quote()` is specific to escaping things for use in PHP's regex functions. Is that the correct way to escape for use in MongoDB?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I believe so. I couldn't find references for scaping specific to mongodb lib through...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  CarlosCarucce thank you !! Do you know an answer for my other question too ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64960899/php-mongodb-aggregate-match-and-group-and-addtoset